# Admin Rights to Sharepoint

Tags: 2007, check-in

How do I give admin rights to files in sharepoint 2007? I don't want to have to sit and check files in, I would like my assistant to do that. Please advise.

Comment: If the files are checked out to you, then the changes in the files are only visible to you.  Assuming your assistant uses a different windows logon, he will not be able to see your changes, even if you give him administrative rights.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my comment above, if you have files checked out to you, the changes to those files are only visible to you.  So, even if you give your assistant full control, she will not be able to check in files she cannot see.

However, if you have SharePoint Designer, there is an easy way to check in multiple documents.  [Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c96350be-95c8-4443-aa8f-f5890894e486/check-in-multiple-files-at-once?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) is a link to do that, but here is the method described on that page:

1. Open the site in Sharepoint designer
2. Find the files you want to check in, in a document library
3. In the 'Folder List' on the left-hand pane, select the files (using shift or Ctrl) you wish to check in. They'll have a check mark next to them.
4. Right Click and choose "Check In" or "Undo Check Out"

Comment: The problem is, is that the person that loaded the files onto SharePoint did not set the appropriate properties so therefore I have to edit the properties for each and every file. Is there a way out of this method? I have to go in select edit properties on the drop down then for document type put that in and hit save in order to check in the document. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Please read [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23092/changing-column-values-metadata-of-multiple-files-at-once-in-multiple-folders) thread and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Along the point Jeff made, you can give the user the ability to override the check-out, however you will lose any changes made.  The only way to check-in a document and keep the changes made is to use the account that made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

That is not entirely correct.

If when you check-out a document you do not select the option "Use my local drafts folder", the edited content remains on the server and the administrator (your secretary) can check-in the document with your latest changes.

[image]

If the default setting in Microsoft Word in your computer is to use the option, you can actually change this default behavior using the instructions from the article [Disable Check Out To Local Drafts Folder](http://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/disable-check-out-to-local-drafts-folder/)

However, to be honest, if you do not wish to use the check-in/out functionality as intended, I am not sure why you wish to use it at all.